# Fail to login with newly created user on DotNetNuke

Tags: authentication, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I try to register an account on a DNN website. 
I get the activation link on my email address, click on it, get the message  "*Your account has been successfully verified".*

[image: Your account has been successfully verified]

After I type the password and click login I get the error *"A critical error has occurred. An unexpected error has occurred"*

[image: A critical error has occurred. An unexpected error has occurred]

If I try to login with the chosen user and password I get this error. *"Login Failed. Please remember that passwords are case sensitive"*

[image: A critical error has occurred. An unexpected error has occurred]

The user appears in the database, if I get the password and the password salt from the admin user and update the new user directly in the table, the login works just fine.

Currently in User Account Settings > Registration Form Type ( Custom  ) > Registration Fields I got only *"Email"* . If I add *"Password"* and *"ConfirmPassword"* everything works just fine, but this is not an option.

P.S. I can login on the admin username and my dnn version is 07.01.02 (356)

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Edited : This was caused in a custom plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is another bug in dnn version 7.1.2 when [changing password](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/forumid/108/postid/491567/scope/posts). 
The solution is to go to Host -> Host Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Membership Management and set the following:

- Enable password history? = yes
- Number of passwords to store = 0

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Admin, Event Viewer and see if there is any additional information available.

Also check and make sure that you are connecting to the database (connection string settings are in web.config -- make sure that BOTH strings are correct) and verify that the db user has dbo privileges in the database.